# Do while and Switch

Tags: javascript

I would like to manipulate a `do while` and a `switch`. I have 2 options which are "enter" and "exit".

When I enter the choice `1` I want to add the text `"Option 1"` to the document. 
However, I don't see anything until I enter `2`

```js
var choice = 0;

function main() {

  do {

    document.write("*****MENU*****" + "<br>");
    document.write("1) - Enter " + "<br>");
    document.write("2) - Exit " + "<br>");

    choice = parseInt(prompt("Enter your option please: "));

    switch (choice) {
      case 1:
        document.write("Option 1");
        break;

    }

  } while (choice != 2);

}
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: As you can see, when @George edited your question to make it interactive, a call to `main` has been added and the snippet seems to work as expected. So the obvious question is: did you call `main` somewhere?

Comment: @George right, but if that's the case the problem is not reproducible. Also, " I don't see anything until I enter 2" that's not what I see when I test the snippet and it wasn't in the original question. You should revert that part of the question because it completely changes the meaning.

Comment: @George it's not a good practice to change question. you should not change code or anything which changes meaning of question.

Comment: @George As I said, that's not what I see. Look [here](https://i.imgur.com/prSCpBc.png). I never closed the `prompt` or inputted 2, just pressed OK after inputting 1.

Comment: @cmprogram: my loop has a problem

Comment: @Federico klez Culloca my problem is the loop

Comment: @Code Maniac: my function main is on my body <body onload="main()" my problem is my loop

Comment: @anais_stemb than please try to better explain the problem

Comment: @George we can nitpick until tomorrow about whether the problem is or isn't reproducible, but as it stands there's not enough information. And yes, your edit *does* change the meaning of the question. "I see nothing" is not the same "I see nothing unless I do X", especially when crucial information like "on browser Y" is missing and you just assumed it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var choice = 0;

function main() {

  do {

    document.write("*****MENU*****" + "<br>");
    document.write("1) - Enter " + "<br>");
    document.write("2) - Exit " + "<br>");

    choice = parseInt(prompt("Enter your option please: "));

    switch (choice) {
      case 1:
        document.write("Option 1");
        break;
    }
    break; // You Must use break to exit the do while 
  } while (choice != 2);

}
```

It executes a block of code for as long as a specified condition is true. **do...while** statement, which is very similar to while with the major difference being that a do...while loop will always execute once, even if the condition is never true

Comment: Uhm... so what? I mean, that's not the question

Comment: then what you are expecting?

Comment: @Suyambu Education: ohhhh thank you a lot, my problem was the break mercy

Comment: @Federico klez Culloca: my problem was the break; thanks anyways

Comment: Then I really didn't didn't understand the question. I mean, if I ran your code it gave the expected results (unless I pressed "Cancel" which just kept on looping)

Comment: @Federico klez Culloca: In fact, I would like to get as result next.

I enter "1"  via prompt, I visualize the text for example "option1" for the case 1. ok 
Then prompt ask again a choice I enter 2, I have option2 for case 2 

For now it doesn't works

Answer (score 0):

You  missed to call the `main()` function.

```js
var choice = 0;

function main()
{

    do{

        document.write("*****MENU*****" + "<br>");
        document.write("1) - Enter " + "<br>");
        document.write("2) - Exit " + "<br>");

        choice = parseInt(prompt("Enter your option please: "));

        switch(choice){
                case 1 :
                        document.write("Option 1");
                break;

        }

    } while(choice != 2);

}
main()         //You missed this
```

Comment: I don't think that is the answer, since he obviously stated that he enters the choice 1 which implies he already executed the main function.

Comment: @Mirakurun it's already getting added the only thing is he's stopping alert only on 2( whic means exit according to question)